# Hibernate: Inconsistent results with @OneToOne unidirectional relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one, hibernate-annotations

I'm getting inconsistent results with @OneToOne unidirectional relationships in Hibernate. Specifically, I have a `User` table with a couple of relationships to other tables: `Foo` and `Bar`.

`Foo` is mapped to `User` by the user's `uuid` property (a String). `Bar` is mapped to `User` by the user's `id` property (an Integer).

My entities look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "uuid")
    private String uuid;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "uuid", referencedColumnName = "frn_object_uuid")
    private Foo foo;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "frn_user_id")
    private Bar bar;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Foo")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "frn_object_uuid")
    private String objectUuid;

    @Column(name = "foo")
    private String foo;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Bar")
public class Bar {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "frn_user_id")
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "bar")
    private String bar;

    // getters and setters
}
```

When I perform a read on the `User` object, I get results for `Foo` but NULL for `Bar`.

What am I missing here? I'm able to get results if I make `Bar` a bidirectional relationship using `mappedBy`...very strange.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Only difference between `Foo` and `Bar` seems to be that `Bar` is using the generated id primary key to join vs a String. Most times I've seen the unidirectional on a primary key, the child doesn't have it's own primary key, it shares it with the parent using `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`

Comment: @MagicMan Yeah, it definitely has to do with the Primary Key, but I tried doing a `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` and that didn't work. It's weird because this does work: https://gist.github.com/sscovil/9008426

Comment: So making it bidirectional makes it work; no where in the Hibernate docs does it say that unidirectional using/PK as a foreign key wouldn't work. Maybe it's because without that foreign key applied  integrity could be violated?

Comment: Problem is, in place of `frn_user_id` I actually have to deal with a `frn_object_id` and a @Where clause that references a `type` column. The type could be "user" or "post". This means I would need to have two properties in the Bar class: `User user` and `Post post`, both with the same @JoinColumn...which doesn't work.